# How to create read replica from MSSQL to MySQL through RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sql-server, database, rds

I have a RDS instance with SQL Server Standard edition. This DB is used for transactions, I want to create read replica but I want the new replica to be MySQL/MariaDB or PostgreSQL. This is because we plan to use reporting software that extracts data directly from our DB.

I don't know if is possible to achieve this. I know that can write some application in some language and use a cron job to execute this every minute but I'm searching a more efficient and elegant solution.

Someone has experience with this? I already read about SymmetricDS but someone has experience with this software and two RDS instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**AWS Database Migration Service**](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) (DMS) - it's pretty good at translating between different SQL engines. Although it says "migration" it can also be used in a *continuous replication mode* where it keeps updating the target database from the source database. That's probably what you need.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this is not possible in RDS. If you really need this I suspect you will need to use a third party solution outside RDS, which will likely involve transformation and latency.

I suggest having your reporting connect to the main database, or an MS SQL replica. If you really need it to by MySQL... maybe someone else will have some ideas.